# Uncommon records between two result sets from two different queries

Tags: sql

I have two queries(each on a different table) with a where clause of their own.
Primary keys for two tables have different names but hold same values.
 How do I pull out the records that are in result set1 but not in result set2.

Here is an example of two queries
**Query1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [EntityID],[Year],[Name],[OperationalStatus],[RefTypeID] 
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Entity] 
WHERE [Year]='2014' AND [RefTypeID] IN ('abc','xys')
```

**Query2:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [OrganizationID],[Year],[OperationalStatusID],[Active],[ModifiedBy],[ModifiedDate] 
      FROM [DB2].[dbo].[Organization] WHERE [Year]='2014'
```

Primary key from query1 is [EntityID] and primary key from second query is [OrganizationID]. These two columns hold same values

Comment: Your second query isn't complete, please edit your question to show the actual query. You also need to tell us which column/columns is/are the primary key

Comment: The columns pulled by the two queries are different. How do you decide which records match up?

Comment: Sorry about that. I just edited the second query.

Comment: A `MINUS/EXCEPT` could be the answer, but the column to be considered for matching is not clear to us. `EntityID = OrganizationID` is the only matching column, of all your selected columns in both queries?

Comment: Yes, there is just one column which hold similar values. Table1.[EntityID]=Table2.[OrganizationID]. The first answer below did it. Thank you everybody. This is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT [EntityID],[Year],[Name],[OperationalStatus],[RefTypeID] 
    FROM [DB].[dbo].[Entity] A
    WHERE [Year]='2014' AND [RefTypeID] IN ('abc','xys') AND 
    Not Exists 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT [OrganizationID],[Year],[OperationalStatusID],[Active],[ModifiedBy],     
      [ModifiedDate] 
      FROM [DB2].[dbo].[Organization] D WHERE [FiscalYear]='2014' AND
      A.EntityID = D.OrganizationID AND
      A.Year=D.Year
      A.Name = D. Name
    )
) AS T
```

Comment: @Vignesh, `DISTINCT` is really not needed in the subquery..!! But still no harm to the result actually.